# test multithreading (CompletableFuture) with EasyMock

Tags: java, multithreading, easymock

I would like to add tests for method, which contains CompletableFuture:

```
 public void report(List<String> srcList) {
        if (srcList != null) {
            ...
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
               ....
               srcList.forEach(src-> downloader.send(url)));
        }
 }
```

I would like to test, that method `send` is called. My test looks like:

```
 @Test
 public void _test() {
        List<String> events = new ArrayList();
        events.add("http://xxxx//");
        events.add("http://xxxx//");

        expect(downloader.send(events.get(0))).andReturn("xxx").times(2);
        replay(downloader);
        eventReporter.report(events);

        verify(downloader);
 }
```

And I get such error `Downloader.send("http://xxxx//"): expected: 2, actual: 0`

One way to avoid this error, is to set `Thread.sleep(100);` timeout. Then the thread will wait and verify that the method had called. But this will increase tests time.

Is there other way to test multithreading with EasyMock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bad practice to unit test asynchronoys code with `Thread.sleep()` method
because if it even works test will be unstable and flicker (run 3 times 2 pass and 1 fail) 
if you set up big time of sleep and write few tests like this you meet a big time of execution 
that may be exceed dozens of seconds. For complete this task you need to decouple asynchronous part
of you code from synchronous. Example how to do it:

```
class Service {

    private Downloader downloader;
    private ExecutorService service;

    public Service (Downloader downloader, ExecutorService service) {
        //set variables
    }

    public void doWork(List<String> list) {
        for (String item : list) {
            service.submit(() -> {
                downloader.download(item);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

ExecutorService is interface and we need to make our Service that will be synchronous

```
class SycnronousService impliments ExecutorService {

    //methods empty implementations

    public void submit(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run(); //run immediately
    }

    //methods empty implementations
}

public class ServiceTest {

    public void shouldPassAllItemsToDownloader() {
        Downloader mockDownloader = AnyMockFramework.mockIt();
        Service service = new Service(mockDownloader, new SycnronousService());
        List<String> tasks = Arrays.asList("A", "B");
        service.doWork(tasks);
        verify(mockDownloader).download("A"); //verify in your way with EasyMock
        verify(mockDownloader).download("B"); //verify in your way with EasyMock
        // no more Timer.sleep() , test runs immeadetely  
    }

}
```

You need to replace `CompletableFuture` to something like in my example, because 
unit testing this code not able in this way.
Later in you app you will be able to replace `SycnronousService` to asynchronous implementation and all will be work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @joy-dir 's answer. And you should probably do what she said to simplify your testing.

For the sake of completeness, your problem here is that the `verify` is called before your tasks being actually finished. There are many things you could do.

One is to loop on `verify`.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    List<String> events = new ArrayList();
    events.add("http://xxxx//");
    events.add("http://xxxx//");

    expect(downloader.send(events.get(0))).andReturn("xxx").times(2);
    replay(downloader);
    report(events);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            verify(downloader);
            return;
        } catch(AssertionError e) {
            // wait until it works
        }
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    verify(downloader);
}
```

It won't sleep a long time for nothing when successful. However, you indeed need to make sure you wait enough to prevent the test from being flaky.

Another solution is actually to use the `CompletableFuture` returned by `runAsync`. I prefer this solution.

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> report(List<String> srcList) {
    if (srcList != null) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> srcList.forEach(src-> downloader.send(src)));
    }
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}

@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    List<String> events = new ArrayList();
    events.add("http://xxxx//");
    events.add("http://xxxx//");

    expect(downloader.send(events.get(0))).andReturn("xxx").times(2);
    replay(downloader);
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = report(events);

    future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    verify(downloader);
}
```

Finally, there is a hackish way. You ask the common pool if it is done. It is hackish because something else might use it. So it's cute but I wouldn't really recommend it.

```
@Test
public void test3() throws Exception {
    List<String> events = new ArrayList();
    events.add("http://xxxx//");
    events.add("http://xxxx//");

    expect(downloader.send(events.get(0))).andReturn("xxx").times(2);
    replay(downloader);
    report(events);

    while(!ForkJoinPool.commonPool().isQuiescent()) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }

    verify(downloader);
}
```